# Easy way to identify Orbits and Stabilizers of geometric shapes

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning about orbits and stabilizers of geometric shapes. Is there an easy way to tell if a shape such as a equilateral triangular prism has one orbit and is there an easy way to find the stabilizers. I know this shape has 1 orbit of order 3 if we take a rectangular face and a stabilizer of order 3, but I do not see this quickly. Is there a neat way to easily identify the orbits and stabilizers of these geometric shapes that are harder to visualize?

Comment: If your geometric shape is the convex hull of a finite set of points then as a first approximation the automorphism group would be a subgroup of the permutation group of those points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, a dodecahedron or say a tetrahedron is a convex hull of a finite set of points so there should only be one orbit? Is there an easy way to identify the size of this orbit?

Comment: Not always. Think about an isosceles triangle. As a first approximation it has three vertices so it's symmetry IS CONTAINED in s3. But the vertex which is adjacent to two equal edges is special. It cannot be moved. That cuts down symmetry to S2. (It can be seen as symmetry of edges which is one dimensional simplices). For a three dimensional figure... A first approximation would be symmetry of vertices, then edges (obviously edges of different lengths cannot go to each other) then 2-dimensional faces....

Comment: So a 3 dimensional figure that is convex hull of a finite set of points should then have only 1 orbit?

Comment: No, because any transformation of the  3d object will have to take faces to faces. So there will be restrictions imposed by different type of faces the polytope has.